# FormattedText.GetMaxTextWidths returns null - why?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to find out how wide some text is. This is my code:

```
FormattedText ft = new FormattedText("Line 1\r\nLine 2",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
                fontSize,
                brush);
double[] w = ft.GetMaxTextWidths();
```

The problem is that w is always null. Do you know why?

Comment: I just realized my answer tells why w is always null, but doesn't help you get  the width of the text.  For that you can use `FormattedText.Width`.  For multi-line text, it gives the length of the longest line.  If you want the length of each line, I suppose you'll have to set the `Text` property to each line individually. Also, if you do set `MaxTextWidth`, `Width` will be the length within that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormattedTextClass` doesn't tell you what the maximum line widths are.  It works the other way around; You tell it the maximum widths and it figures out how to display the text.

This MSDN article has more information:  [Drawing Formatted Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098.aspx)

Taking the sample code and overriding the `OnRender` event of a window, here is what a line of text looks like when no constraint is placed on the width:

[image]

when `MaxTextWidth` is set to 300:

[image]

and when `SetMaxTextWidths` is called passing in a double array of `{ 200, 500, 100 }` (the last width is used for all remaining lines when there are more lines than array entries):

[image]

In all of the above examples, I left the `MaxTextHeight` set to 240.

A couple of notes if you want to run the code from the article in the `OnRender` event of a `Window`:

- Set the window's `Background`
  property to `Transparent`
- Add a line of code to draw a white background behind the text:

> 

```
// Draw a white background
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width, this.Height)));

// Draw the formatted text string to the DrawingContext of the control.
drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point(10, 10));
```